# QTVR-like Panorama in Flash/ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, graphics, quicktime

It has been a few years since I used Actionscript. Back in the day, I made a project that emulated a QTVR panorama (at the time I was using Flash, you could only embed very basic mov files) by simply moving a very long flattened pano image left or right behind a mask. The effect was okay, but not as nice as a real pano, since the perspective was so warped. So now that a couple iterations of Flash have been developed I am curious...

Is there a way now to get a bit closer to a real QTVR? ...or is it now possible to embed a real QTVR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be - download [PaperVision](http://blog.papervision3d.org/), cut your image into strips, then arrange these in ring as 3d planes.

Answer (score 3):

[FlashPanoramas](http://flashpanoramas.com/player/) has worked great for me in the past. One of its newer features is the ability to directly load in QTVR files.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution, one I am currently using on a day to day basis to present plots of land for sale on a website I developed is to use krpano. It is by far the best one out there -- flash-based, XML-powered, very customizable, supports plug-ins, hands down the best.

http://www.krpano.com/

It has a flash viewer and also all the tools you need to create the panoramas.